# How to parse data in Hive by character &

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, hive

The data looks like this:

```
fsid=4778&awid=5&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.abcd.com%2f2-03&pfhid=-356847895&event=Login&Incorrect=False
fsid=3478&awid=5&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.abcd.com%2f2-03&pfhid=-356847895&event=Login&userid=10598&Incorrect=False
```

I want to see how many fsid I have in total and how many userid in total, a lot of records have userid missing. 
I am using Hive, maybe it's not the best approach, I know how to do this in python if this is a flat text file. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try regular expressions ?

Comment: @Naveen You mean use python? I don't know how to use it in a distributed way. Now i'm thinking just loop through all the files using python. but it's not the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regexp.

```
Select sum(case when fsid   is not null then 1 else 0 end) as count_fsid
    ,  sum(case when userid is not null then 1 else 0 end) as count_userid
    from
        (Select regexp_extract(my_string, '.*fsid=(//d*)&.*')   as fsid
              , regexp_extract(my_string, '.*userid=(//d*)&.*') as userid
        from my table
        ) a ;
```